# Can I install two xampp in my Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, xampp

I am a Web Developer. I am install two xampp version 1.8.1 in my Ubuntu 12.04. I have install one xampp in /opt folder and another in other ntfs partition.
Please tell me how I install them.

Answer (score 0):

`XAMPP` doesn't need any installation. You can only run one version at a time (using `/opt/lampp/lampp start` or `/opt/xampp/xampp start`).

You can place both of them in `/opt/lamppp` and `/opt/lampp2` so that you can run each other alternatively.